# Snackbar not working on Modal Table Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

I have implemented a functionality of deletion and on successful completion I have to display a snackbar with the message received from backend. I am able to get the correct response but the snackbar is not accessible. I think the scope is different as it is mat-dialog table from where I am deleting a user.
TS Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
      public commonService :CommonService
    } {}
// I am opening dialog from this parent component
 openDialog(u, c){
     this.response = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(u.Data));
     for(var i =0;i<Object.keys(this.response).length;i++){
      this.final.push(this.response[i]);
    }
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogExample, {
         data: {arrayDialog: this.finalUsers, c}
       });
     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
       this.finalUsers = [];
     });
   }


//this is where the mat dialog is
 @Component({
    selector: 'dialog-example',
    templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
  })
  export class DialogExample {
    constructor(
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogExample>,
      public dialog:MatDialog,
      public commonService :CommonService,
    } {}
//some function
              //if deletion is successful
              dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((confirmed: boolean) => {
              if (confirmed) { //if deletion is confirmed
              this.deleteMessage = this.details.msg;
              this.commonService.showSnackBar(this.deleteMessage);
```

Commonservice Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  public spinnerSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  public showSnackBar(message){
    this.snackBar.open(message,'',{
      duration: 5000   
    });}}
```

How can I display the snackbar with the message? I get the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSnackBar' of undefined. I have noticed I am not able to call any function, service from inside afterClosed. Any workaround?

Comment: update the commonservice code

Comment: update the commonservice code as in? It is a normal service I have created which I using in multiple components. I am also using it in parent component and it is working fine. I am not able to access it on mat dialog

Comment: yes. update code here

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: Can you put a link to a minimum reproducible sample?

Comment: Hi @canbax I am sorry I tried but was not able to produce this error in any online medium

Comment: did you tried stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/angular/pyrgjeodnnl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.service.ts https://stackblitz.com

Comment: I tried it but I could not replicate the  issue. Actually I am calling a lambda function in AWS to get the results and I am not able to access the commonservice

Answer (score 0):

Commonservice Code:

Try this..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class CommonService {
    
      public spinnerSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
    
      constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}
    
      public showSnackBar(message){
        let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
        config.duration = 5000;
        this.snackBar.open(message,undefined,config);
      }
    }
```

Comment: this.snackBar.open("Information has been deleted successfully!", undefined, config);

Comment: I have added an important piece of info in the edit. Can you take a look now. I guess I somehow missed it. Actually delete is called on afterClosed() so I am not able to call any service or function over there. What could be the work around for that?

Comment: I have added the part where I am opening the dialog box from